# How to change a local variable in mysql keeping reference to itself?

Tags: mysql, sql

My credit table has following data

```
Id
1
2
3
```

I want to decrement a variable declared inside a stored procedure by selecting id from credit table, keeping reference to itself .

I have done this using session variable in the following  way

```
delimiter //
create procedure xxx()
begin
declare var int default 200;
 set @t=100;
 select @t:=@t-id as result from credit;

end //
```

The above stored procedure returns the following result

```
result
99
97
94
```

My question is how to achieve the same result set using mysql local variable.

Answer (score 0):

Leaving aside the utlity of applying such a function to seqientially allocated integers and the fact that, in the absence of an order by clause, you can't guarantee consistent behaviour, have you tried....

```
delimiter //
create procedure xxx()
begin
  declare var int default 200;
  set @t=100;
  UPDATE credit SET credit.result=(@t:=@t-id) 
  ORDER BY id;
end //
```

(I haven't, so not guaranteees here)

Comment: my question was how use local variable as like session variable
what you have described i don't understand